# XML Keyboard Characters to TeX Characters - LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, lua, luacode

I would like to convert all the XML Keyboard Characters to LaTeX Code Conversion. For Example `$` should convert to `\$`, `{` should convert to `\{` in LaTeX. How to achieve this?

I know it's possible to do `find and replace` format. But i would like to do `Lua function`.

My MWE IS:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}


\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}
local domobject = require "luaxml-domobject"
sample = [[
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<art>
<title>Scattering of flexural waves an electric current</title>
<para>Smart testing structures are $a+b$ components Reduce acoustic noise. used in engineering applications that are capable of sensing or reacting to their environment change their mechanical properties. in a predictable and desired manner. In addition to carrying mechanical loads, alleviate vibration, reduce acoustic noise, change their mechanical properties as required or monitor their own condition.</para>
</art>
]]
local dom = domobject.parse(sample)
    dom=string.gsub(sample,"%$(.-)%$","\\$ %1\\$")
print(dom)
\end{luacode*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: do you need to  convert $ to `\$` ? You could more simply print the string back to tex with a catcode table in which $ had catcode 12 so wasn't special, similarly `{`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: How about to convert XML Processing Instructions tag (like `<?LuaLaTeX This is some text need to print in LaTeX?>` should convert to LaTeX Code `This is some text need to print in LaTeX`.

Comment: Maybe a tool like [xml2tex](https://github.com/transpect/xml2tex) could be useful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `luaxml-transform` library does escaping:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}


\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}
local domobject = require "luaxml-domobject"
local transform = require "luaxml-transform"
sample = [[
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<art>
<title>Scattering of flexural waves an electric current</title>
<para>Smart testing structures are $a+b$ components Reduce acoustic noise. {used in engineering applications} that are capable of sensing or reacting to their environment change their mechanical properties. in a predictable and desired manner. In addition to carrying mechanical loads, alleviate vibration, reduce acoustic noise, change their mechanical properties as required or monitor their own condition.</para>
<para>Another paragraph.</para>
</art>
]]
local dom = domobject.parse(sample)
local transformer = transform.new()
transformer:add_action("title", "\\section{@<.>}")
transformer:add_action("para", "@<.>\\par")
transform.print_tex(transformer:process_dom(dom))
\end{luacode*}
\end{document}
```

In this example, I've configured `<title>` to produce a section and `<para>` to produce a paragraph. The `@<.>` string is replaced by the element's content. The result looks like this:

[image]

You can add a new escapes. From the `LuaXML` docs:

> You may want to escape certain characters, or replace them with LaTeX
> commands. You can use the unicodes table contained in the
> Transform object:

```
local transformer = transform.new()
-- you must use the Unicode character code
transformer.unicodes[124] = "\\textbar"
local text = '<x>|</x>'
local result = transformer:parse_xml(text)
transform.print_tex(result)
```

Edit:

This is how you can process the `<?LuaLaTeX`  processing instructions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}


\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}
local domobject = require "luaxml-domobject"
local transform = require "luaxml-transform"
sample = [[
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<art>
<title>Scattering of flexural waves an electric current</title>
<para>Smart testing structures are $a+b$ components Reduce acoustic noise. {used in engineering applications} that are capable of sensing or reacting to their environment change their mechanical properties. in a predictable and desired manner. In addition to carrying mechanical loads, alleviate vibration, reduce acoustic noise, change their mechanical properties as required or monitor their own condition.</para>
<para>Another paragraph.  <?LuaLaTeX Sample \textit{Text Here}?></para>
</art>
]]

local dom = domobject.parse(sample)


-- the transform library doesn't support procesing instructions transformation, so we need to 
-- replace them with elements that can be then transformed 
local function process_instructions(el)
  for _, child in ipairs(el:get_children()) do
    local ntype = child:get_node_type()
    -- replace <?LuaLaTeX ... ?>
    if ntype == "PI" and child._name=="LuaLaTeX" then
      local text = child._attr[ "_text" ]
      local newel = el:create_element("lualatex-instruction", {text = text})
      child:replace_node(newel)
    end
    -- process children elements
    if child:is_element() then
      process_instructions(child)
    end
  end
end

process_instructions(dom:root_node())


local transformer = transform.new()
transformer:add_action("title", "\\section{@<.>}")
transformer:add_action("para", "@<.>\\par")
-- handle the processing instruction
transformer:add_custom_action("lualatex-instruction", function(el)
  return el:get_attribute("text")
end)
transform.print_tex(transformer:process_dom(dom))
\end{luacode*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How to transform xml processing instruction tags? Example: <?LuaLaTeX Sample Text Here?> should convert LaTeX Code to `Sample Text Here`.

Comment: @Balaji you need to convert them to elements first. See the update

Comment: Its working fine except `\vspace` command. <?LuaLaTeX \vskip12pt Sample \hspace{8pt} \textit{Text Here} and \vspace{12pt} vertical space?>. For `\vskip12pt` and `\hspace{8pt}` is working and `\vspace{12pt}` is not working. How to do this?

Comment: @Balaji this works in the same way as if you wrote it directly in LaTeX